# Does my code with derived type pointers leak memory?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

My IDE is Code::Blocks 17.2 with compiler GFortran 6.3.1

The all code is:

```
PROGRAM EES_TEST

USE , NON_INTRINSIC :: DERIVED_TYPE

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: I , ALLOC_ERR , DEALLOC_ERR
LOGICAL :: GLOBAL_ERR

CLASS ( TRONA ) , POINTER :: P_TRA
TYPE ( TRONA ) , ALLOCATABLE , TARGET :: TRAN(:)

IF ( .NOT. ALLOCATED ( TRAN ) ) ALLOCATE ( TRAN ( 2 ) , STAT = ALLOC_ERR )

IF ( ALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP ("PROBLEM WITH MEMORY ALLOCATION - TRAN!!!")

OPEN ( UNIT = 15 , FILE = 'INPUT.TXT' , ACTION = 'READ' )

  DO I = 1 , 2

     P_TRA => TRAN ( I )
     GLOBAL_ERR = P_TRA%UCI()

     IF ( GLOBAL_ERR .EQV. .TRUE. ) STOP ("ERROR WITH READING FROM OUTPUT.TXT!")

  END DO

CLOSE ( 15 )

IF ( ALLOCATED ( TRAN ) ) DEALLOCATE ( TRAN , STAT = DEALLOC_ERR )

IF ( DEALLOC_ERR .NE. 0 ) STOP ("PROBLEM WITH MEMORY DEALLOCATION - TRAN!!!")

END PROGRAM EES_TEST

MODULE DERIVED_TYPE

IMPLICIT NONE

TYPE , PUBLIC :: TRONA

  PRIVATE

    REAL :: Sn
    REAL :: Vn

  CONTAINS

    PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: UCI => UCI_POD_TRONA
    PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: TAKE_Sn => TAKE_POD_Sn
    PROCEDURE , PUBLIC :: TAKE_Vn => TAKE_POD_Vn

END TYPE TRONA

PRIVATE :: UCI_POD_TRONA
PRIVATE :: TAKE_POD_Sn , TAKE_POD_Vn

CONTAINS

  FUNCTION UCI_POD_TRONA ( THIS ) RESULT ( WRONG )

    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS ( TRONA ) :: THIS
    LOGICAL :: WRONG

    WRONG = .FALSE.

    READ ( 15 , * , ERR = 100 ) THIS%Sn
    READ ( 15 , * , ERR = 101 ) THIS%Vn

  RETURN

  100 WRITE (*,*) "WRONG FORMAT - INPUT 100!"
  WRONG = .TRUE.
  STOP

  101 WRITE (*,*) "WRONG FORMAT - INPUT 101!"
  WRONG = .TRUE.
  STOP

  END FUNCTION UCI_POD_TRONA

  FUNCTION TAKE_POD_Sn ( THIS ) RESULT ( POD_Sn )

    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS ( TRONA ) :: THIS
    REAL :: POD_Sn

    POD_Sn = THIS%Sn

  RETURN
  END FUNCTION TAKE_POD_Sn


  FUNCTION TAKE_POD_Vn ( THIS ) RESULT ( POD_Vn )

    IMPLICIT NONE

    CLASS ( TRONA ) :: THIS
    REAL :: POD_Vn

    POD_Vn = THIS%Vn

  RETURN
  END FUNCTION TAKE_POD_Vn

END MODULE DERIVED_TYPE
```

I am very new in object oriented programing in Fortran so I need an explanation about using the object pointer for calling methods from derived types. In this case I want to check is there any problem with memory leaking and if it is case is there method for checking how much memory was lost and in which line? Another thing is nullifying the derived type pointer. How to do that for this case?

Comment: The code that you have provided does not seem to be a small working example code explaining your problem. With regards to learning OOP Fortran, a very good (but rather comprehensive) resource is "Chapter 14: Object-oriented programming" of the book "Modern Fortran Explained" by Metcalf, Reid, Cohen, 2011. You can access parts of the chapter in Google books.

Comment: I also think we need a more complete code sample. Pleade make it compilable and runable. See [mcve]. Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In the end I did post an answer but I fear you will tell us that in the *real code* you do allocate something. In that case you must show the complete real code.

Comment: @VladimirF Your fear is legitimate. I make a change to code in question.

Comment: Nothing changes, still no pointer allocation. No memory leak i possible.

Comment: @Vladimir F Maybe in this case: `ALLOCATE ( P_TRA )`? Please, can you show me the case in which this code can be changed for memory leak explanation because i want to learn rukes for avoid that in the further coding process.

Comment: Memory lesk happens when you loose a pointer that was pointeng to somethinh pointer-allocated. `allocate(p_tra); p_tra => somewhere_else`. It is actually a very simple concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, unless you allocate something somewhere, you *cannot* have memory leaks. It is simply impossible. You can only leak something you allocate as a pointer target, nothing else.

In your code you have no `allocate()` for a pointer, so there cannot be any memory leaks.

For a memory leak to happen, two things must happen in sequence.

1. An anonymous pointer target must be allocated. That is possible only through the allocate statement

   ```
   allocate(p_tra)
   ```
2. The pointer to the target is lost. Either it is redirected somewhere else

   ```
   p_tra => somewhere_else
   ```

   Or it ceases to exist, because it is a local variable of a subroutine that finishes or it is a component of a structure which is deallocated or similar...

You can always use GCC sanitizations `-fssnitize=leak` or `valgrind` to check for memory leaks.

Regarding the nulifying, just use the `nulify` statement or assign to `null()`. It is a pointer like any other.

```
p_tra => null()
```