# Deallocate pointer in fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

I have troubles to understand pointers in Fortran.

I have the following code

```
    Module testA  
        Type PtrType  
            Real*8,dimension(:),pointer :: ptr  
            Integer ::N  
        End Type  
        contains  
                   
        Subroutine AllocateP( A )    
           Implicit None  
           Type( PtrType ) ::A  
           Allocate( A%ptr( 1:A%N ) )  
        End Subroutine AllocateP  
     
        Subroutine DeAllocateP( A )  
           Implicit None  
           Type( PtrType ) ::A  
           Deallocate( A%ptr )  
        End Subroutine DeAllocateP   
                                
                                  
        Subroutine NullifyP( A )  
           Implicit None  
           Type( PtrType ) ::A  
           Nullify( A%ptr )     
        End Subroutine NullifyP      
                                
End Module testA                
                               

Program main           
                       
        use testA      
        Implicit None  
        Integer ::i  
        Type( PtrType ) ::A  
        Real*8,Target,Allocatable,dimension( : ) ::B  

        A%N  =  10000  
  
  
        Do i = 1 , 10000000  
           Allocate( B( 1:A%N ) )  
           Call AllocateP( A )     
           A%ptr => B              
           Deallocate( B )         
           Call NullifyP( A )      
        End Do
End Program
```

here

When I execute this code it overflows the memory of my computer.
I also tried using the DeallocateP routine on the pointer but this throws
the following error during execution
double free or corruption (!prev): 0x000000000255cf60 ***
I am using the gfortran-6 compiler.

Can anyone give me a hint how to properly deallocate or free the memory of a pointer in Fortran.

Comment: Do you understand what [pointer assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61127387/3157076) means, in particular with regards to potential memory leaks? (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49462792/3157076).)

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for your respond. I was reading the link you posted, And I think I understand what it is about, But I don't see how this can fix my problem. Because I think I am doing the association of the pointer correct. But still I don't see how to free the memory properly

Comment: In `allocateP` you allocate memory for `A%P` but then immediately throw that reference away (without deallocating it) by pointing to `B` instead. It isn't clear to me what want to do, but you want to allocate `B` or `A%P` but not both. And probably you shouldn't be using pointers at all, but allocatables.

Comment: You allocate some memory for your pointer. You then make your pointer point somewhere totally different, and don't deallocate that memory. You do this lots of times, and so run out of memory. But why do you want to use a pointer? Most things in Fortran are better done using allocatable arrays.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for you comment this solves my problem.

Comment: @Ian I am working with a code not written by me that uses a similar structure and there the memory leakage occurs.